# ¿como parar un bucle en swift?

Tags: swift

como puedo parar el bucle cuando la app esta otra vez en primer plano en foreground?
este es mi codigo en appdelegate
alguien me puede ayudar?

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    var finished = false
    var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0);
    bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName:"MyBackgroundTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        // Time is up.
        if bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid {
            // Do something to stop our background task or the app will be killed
            finished = true
        }
    })
    // Perform your background task here
    print("The task has started")
    while !finished {
        print("Not finished")
        // when done, set finished to true
        // If that doesn't happen in time, the expiration handler will do it for us
    }
    // Indicate that it is complete
    application.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregando el willEnterForeground o didEnterForeground podrias modificar el valor del bool que usas para colgar el while

```
var finished = false

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    finished = true
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    finished = false
    var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0);
    bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName:"MyBackgroundTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        // Time is up.
        if bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid {
            // Do something to stop our background task or the app will be killed
            finished = true
        }
    })
    // Perform your background task here
    print("The task has started")
    while !finished {
        print("Not finished")
        // when done, set finished to true
        // If that doesn't happen in time, the expiration handler will do it for us
    }
    // Indicate that it is complete
    application.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
}
```

Comment: no funciona al poner "finished = true" en func applicationWillEnterForeground no para el bucle

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir parar un Bucle en Swift debes etiquetarlo y luego salir con la sentencia break

```
label_loop: for item in json["data"].arrayValue {
   if (count == 30) {
    break label_loop
   }
}
```

Comment: me podrias hacer tu el codigo ya que soy novato en swift y no se como hacerlo. gracias

Comment: claro dime que necesitas exactamente?

Comment: podria contactar de alguna manera contigo? porque por escrito no se como explicarme. gracias